# How to connect user data with other table?

Tags: mysql

I'am creating simple web browser game. Already I have register and login form that works. I have a database and table with user information:
userId
userName
userEmail
userPass

I need to have additional data - resources. I must create new table resources and I want to connect this two information to 1 user (1 userId). My idea is to create new table resources with:
userId (must be the same as in user table)
wood
iron
stone

What is a solution of this problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that database design choiches are usually based on the kind of queries you want to do, I think you have two alternatives.

First option is following the path you describe, meaning in the `resources` table you have one column for each type of resources

```
resources
user_id (fk for id of user) | wood_amount | iron_amount | stone_amount
```

This is the simplest design, but if tomorrow you want to add another type of resource you will be forced to add a column. Then another. Then another. Then another.

The other option is designing the relationship between `users` and `resources` as a standard `many-to-many` relationship, meaning you will have three tables

```
user
the one you already have

resource
resource_id | resource_desc

user_resources
user_id (fk to id of user) | resource_id (fk to id of resource | amount
```

This way querying the database for a user's resources may require and additional join, but the addition of new types of resources will be just an insert into the `resource` table.

Comment: Thank you for that. I know is simple for you but I will just create new column to current user table. After register new user i can create all info about userId userName userEmail userPass and starting resources | wood_amount | iron_amount | stone_amount at one time . I'am starting with mysql and php so maybe letter I will improve update this. Now I need to see that work for my motivation. Thanks a lot , I will follow your way in other time.